# Windows Roaming Profile Reverting to Local Profile

Tags: active-directory, domain, windows-server-2012, roaming-profile

I'm trying to set up roaming profiles within a Windows Server 2012 domain. Here is what I did:

- I created a shared folder, which I am able to access at `\\dc1\profile` when logged in as the roaming user. (share & ntfs permissions are set to Everyone - FC for testing)
- I set the user's profile to use `\\dc1\profile\%username%` in the user's properties.

When I log in to the domain as the user I am getting kicked back to the local profile. A folder gets created in the profile share called <username>.V2 that is filled with the default folders but for some reason this isn't the profile being used.

The only error showing up in my event log is a printer driver error (not installed).

I have also tried using `\\dc1\profile\%username%.V2` as the profile path but I get the same result.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the domain client can:

-reach the domain servers IP address?

-resolve the domain address to an IP?

-resolve the servers FQDN to an IP?

Also this article may be helpful when trying to determine the minimum permissions: [Microsoft Roaming Profiles Security Permissions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737633%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)